# How to check the number of occurrence of an element in a ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, count

We have an array,

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5,2]
```

Now, I need to get the occurrence of each element in the ruby array one by one. So, here the ocuurrence of element '1' is 1 times. Occurrence of '2' is 3 times and so on.

Edited and added the below line later as most of the answers were submitted misinterpreting my question:

```
That means, I need to take the occurrence of a single element at a time.
```

How I could get the count?

Comment: You changed the question, so all answers apart of yours became invalid...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [enum#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
[1,2,3,2,4,5,2].reduce Hash.new(0) do |hash, num|
  hash[num] += 1
  hash
end
```

Output

```
{1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5,2]    
p a.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |memo, i| memo[i] += 1; memo }
# => {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Requires `ruby >= 2.2`

```
a.group_by(&:itself).tap{|h| h.each{|k, v| h[k] = v.length}}
# => {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```

Comment: hm, never heard about `itself`, I get `undefined method 'itself' for 1:Fixnum` with Ruby 2.1

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, that's because you're not using the latest and greatest. [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself), which has been in the works for some time, has finally arrived in v.2.2! Hurray!

Comment: @CarySwoveland ah, you meant 2.2, I see:) thank you, I should take a look

Answer (score 1):

That’s a typical `reduce` task:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5,2]
a.inject({}) { |memo,e| 
  memo[e] ||= 0
  memo[e] += 1
  memo 
}
#=> {
#  1 => 1,
#  2 => 3,
#  3 => 1,
#  4 => 1,
#  5 => 1
#}
```

Comment: Perhaps use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to avoid the need to return `memo`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, but this is definitely a task for `reduce`. So I decided to be more clear at the expense of shortness.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
[1,2,3,2,4,5,2].inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, n| h.update(n => h[n]+1)}
# => {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could dispense with the braces there.  `h.update n => h[n]+1` looks even stranger.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Where would you add braces? `Hash#update` returns self, that avoids the need to return the memo.

Comment: Here: `{n => h[n]+1}`. I forgot that Ruby allows a hash to be passed as an argument [without the braces](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=ruby+hash+argument+%22without+braces%22&source=bl&ots=fJCivc3zcz&sig=VK_WdNZ1uc6dhaOPNQDH9VAdLSo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TZbIVPKeFozxoAS6wYH4Ag&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ruby%20hash%20argument%20%22without%20braces%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby >= 2.7 you can call `.tally`:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5,2]
a.tally
 => {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```